# API returing image does not display the image correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Hi I have an api post that ads images a database, and get to get the image. When I issue
http://myserver/dynamic/images/569e61e9-d8ab-44ba-b935-1f7eae8ba39d.jpg
it works fine, get 200 OK response but get binary text displayed in the body not the image itself with the right header image/jpeg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkiop.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGlUn.jpg)
I browsed this forum I saw issues related to interceptor which is off in my postman.

```
byte[] buffer = null; 
var id = Guid.Parse(Path.GetFileName(path).Split(".")[0]); 
using (var db = new EFContext()) { 
  var imageFromDb = await db.Images.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id); 
  buffer = imageFromDb.Data; 
} 

if (buffer != null && buffer.Length > 1) { 
  context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
  context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", ""); 
  await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
} 
else {
  context.Response.StatusCode = 404; 
}
```

Comment: To better assist you, can you please post your request data, tech stack you are using to call your API, and a minimum viable sample of your code?

Comment: It is a get to retrieve images from a sqlite database. Name of images is GUId.jpg ex: 569e61e9-d8ab-44ba-b935-1f7eae8ba39d.jpg. The api is a C# code

Comment: byte[] buffer = null;
var id = Guid.Parse(Path.GetFileName(path).Split(".")[0]);
using (var db = new EFContext())
{
    var imageFromDb =
       await db.Images.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    buffer = imageFromDb.Data;
}
if (buffer != null && buffer.Length > 1)
{
    context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/" +
                        Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "");
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
else
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                }

Comment: byte[] buffer = null;
var id = Guid.Parse(Path.GetFileName(path).Split(".")[0]);
using (var db = new EFContext())
{
    var imageFromDb =
       await db.Images.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    buffer = imageFromDb.Data;
}
if (buffer != null && buffer.Length > 1)
{
    context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/" +
                        Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "");
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
else
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at your code, I can see the issue lies with the MIME type of your response. For serving jpg (jpeg) images, you need to use the following MIME type:

```
image/jpeg
```

Update your code to the following and it will serve the image correctly:

```
byte[] buffer = null; 
var id = Guid.Parse(Path.GetFileName(path).Split(".")[0]); 
using (var db = new EFContext()) { 
  var imageFromDb = await db.Images.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id); 
  buffer = imageFromDb.Data; 
} 

if (buffer != null && buffer.Length > 1) { 
  context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
  context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
  await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
} 
else {
  context.Response.StatusCode = 404; 
}
```

If you're looking for a more dynamic method for assigning the mime type, you can use something like this. Note, this is far from complete and serves as an example:

```
var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path).Replace(".", "");
var mimeType = "image/jpeg";
switch(fileExtension) {
  case "svg":
    mimeType = "image/svg+xml";
  case "png":
    mimeType = "image/png";
  case "jpg":
  case "jpeg":
  case default:
    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
}

//...
context.Response.ContentType = mimeType;
//...
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types for more details on MIME types.

Comment: You are correct, I was extracting the extension from the image file jpg, it works like a charm now, so many thanks and sorry for my delayed reply